# Sql statement to compare two table

Tags: mysql

I have two table with the same structure, i want an sql statement to compare them and see any modified line, deleted or added

Table Product1 :

```
 ________________
|Product  | Price|
|Product1 | 10   |
|Product2 | 8    |
|Product3 | 9    |
|________________|
```

Table Product2 :

```
 ________________
|Product  | Price|
|Product1 | 11   |
|Product2 | 8    |
|Product3 | 9    |
|Product4 | 13   |
|________________|
```

Table result :

```
 ________________
|Product  | Price|
|Product1 | 11   |
|Product4 | 13   |
|________________|
```

Comment: i corrected the result table

Comment: If you want to compare mysql table definitions i made a free tool https://www.tablediff.com/

Answer (score 3):

You want something like this (see below for DDL and DML). This sort of query would be easier with the likes of EXCEPT and MINUS, but we'll have to wait for those...

```
-- first query gets price difference between tables
SELECT p1.* FROM product1 p1, product2 p2
WHERE p1.pname = p2.pname
AND p1.price <> p2.price
-- second query finds extra products in product2 table - unions both of them.
UNION
SELECT p2.* FROM product2 p2, product1 p1
WHERE p2.pname NOT IN(SELECT pname FROM product1);

+----------+-------+
| pname    | price |
+----------+-------+
| Product1 |    10 |
| Product4 |    13 |
+----------+-------+
```

Or - for generality, note where I've added 'Product5', 17 to the product1 table? To get the differences both ways you need to perform the UNION of 3 queries

```
SELECT p1.* FROM product1 p1, product2 p2
WHERE (p1.pname = p2.pname
AND p1.price <> p2.price)
UNION 
SELECT p1.* FROM product1 p1, product2 p2
WHERE p1.pname NOT IN (SELECT pname FROM product2)
UNION
SELECT p2.* FROM product2 p2, product1 p1
WHERE p2.pname NOT IN(SELECT pname FROM product1);
```

which gives

```
+----------+-------+
| pname    | price |
+----------+-------+
| Product1 |    10 |
| Product5 |    17 |
| Product4 |    13 |
+----------+-------+

CREATE TABLE product1
(
  pname VARCHAR(15),
  price int,
  PRIMARY KEY (pname)
);

INSERT INTO product1 VALUES('Product1', 10); 
INSERT INTO product1 VALUES('Product2', 8); 
INSERT INTO product1 VALUES('Product3', 9); 
INSERT INTO product1 VALUES('Product5', 17);    

CREATE TABLE product2

(
  pname VARCHAR(15),
  price int,
  PRIMARY KEY (pname)
);

INSERT INTO product2 VALUES('Product1', 11); 
INSERT INTO product2 VALUES('Product2', 8); 
INSERT INTO product2 VALUES('Product3', 9); 
INSERT INTO product2 VALUES('Product4', 13);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below results for the scenario. Hope it will help.

```
    mysql> create table product1(product varchar(50),price float);
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

    mysql> create table product2 like product1;
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)

    mysql> desc product1;
    +---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | product | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | price   | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    +---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql> desc product2;
    +---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | product | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    | price   | float       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    +---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

    mysql> insert into product1 values('product1','10'),('product2','8'),('product3','9');
    Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.04 sec)
    Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

    mysql> insert into product2 values('product1','11'),('product2','8'),('product3','9'),('product4','13');
    Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.05 sec)
    Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

    mysql> select * from product1 where product not in (select product from product2)
        -> union
        -> select * from product2 where product not in(select product from product1);
    +----------+-------+
    | product  | price |
    +----------+-------+
    | product4 |    13 |
    +----------+-------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from product1 where product not in (select product from product2)
    -> union
    -> select * from product2 where product  in(select product from product1);
+----------+-------+
| product  | price |
+----------+-------+
| product1 |    11 |
| product2 |     8 |
| product3 |     9 |
+----------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> select * from product1 where product in (select product from product2)
    -> union
    -> select * from product2 where product  in(select product from product1);
+----------+-------+
| product  | price |
+----------+-------+
| product1 |    10 |
| product2 |     8 |
| product3 |     9 |
| product1 |    11 |
+----------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from product1 where product in (select product from product2) union select * from product2 where product not  in(select product from product1);
+----------+-------+
| product  | price |
+----------+-------+
| product1 |    10 |
| product2 |     8 |
| product3 |     9 |
| product4 |    13 |
+----------+-------+
```